# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in migration laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm new in laravel and sorry if my English is bad. I have made migrations file and run it

1. create_colleges_table.php

public function up()
    {

```
 Schema::create('colleges', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->char('nim', 10);
        $table->string('email');
        $table->integer('major_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

2. create_majors_table.php

public function up()
    {

```
Schema::create('majors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('major_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And then i make update_colleges_table.php, run it and getting error like this :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `learn_laravel_crud`.`#sql-1558_e3` (errno:
150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `colleges` add constraint `colleges_major_id_foreign` foreign key (`major_id`) references `majors` (`id`))
```

this my code in update_colleges_table.php

public function up()

```
{
    Schema::table('colleges', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('major_id')->references('id')->on('majors');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create `Foreign key` the data type for the `child column` must match the `parent column` exactly.

Since `majors.id` is a `bigIncrements` i.e `unsigned big integer` then `colleges.major_id` also needs to be an `bigInteger`, not a `integer`.

> **So change**

```
 $table->integer('major_id');
```

> **to**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('major_id');
```

Comment: i was follow that, but is still error with same error message

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `learn_laravel_crud`.`#sql-1558_f3` (errno:
150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `colleges` add constraint `colleges_major_id_foreign` foreign key (`major_id`) references `majors` (`id`))

Comment: Finally I know what my mistake is, and your suggest is right, there was as error in the selection of data types